# What's the most REST way to update resources matching some requirements?

Tags: http, rest

I want to do something more `REST` like this:

Select resources whose `field1` equals `foo`, and update `field1` to `bar`

```
UPDATE XXX SET field1 = "bar" WHERE field1="foo"
```

Two solutions as I can see:

1. `GET` items matching my requirement, then `PUT` to update them. Maybe with `Etag` or `If-Match` to guarantee it's atomic.
2. Write a customized `PUT` method handler, so the query string represent the WHERE clause in the SQL and the content of the `PUT` request represent the `SET` clause in SQL

Personally I prefer the latter solution, but in `REST`, the `PUT` method is supposed to *overwrite* *a* resource, not *many* resources at a time, nor just updating some fields of the resource.

I also checked the [HTTP `PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method proposal. It makes "updating some fields of a resource" possible, but it's not used to update many resources at once too.

So what's your solution? I'd like to see your best practice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Random untested ideas:

```
 url: PUT /xxx/*/field1/foo
 body: "bar"
```

or (if you can predict/bound the key range for XXX):

```
PUT /xxx/0,9999999/field1/foo
"bar"
```

or if you are okay with 2 calls, maybe:

```
GET /xxx?field1="foo"
POST /xxx/id1,id2,...,idn/field1
"bar"
```